# Crystal Reports - user can click on fields

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

When i display a report to a user, they are able to click on the fields on the report. this highlights them and turns them blue. Does anybody know how to disable this? I was looking for a read only or a enabled property but no such luck.
Using vb.net 2010 and the built in version of Crystal 13.0.2

here is an example what the text field looks like when the user clicks on it
[example](http://snag.gy/6aOtV.jpg).

Comment: I don think that can be controlled brother!

Comment: I didn't think so either, but figured i would ask... thanks for the reply!